# Can't get detailed error information in ASP.NET MVC website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I just deployed an ASP.NET MVC 3 application to our staging server. Whenever an error occurs, I cannot get the detailed error information, i.e. the "yellow screen of death." Instead, I just get a simple "Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request." message.

My Web.config *does* include the customErrors off, i.e.:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    <assemblies>
      ...
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
  <customErrors mode="off"/>
</system.web>
```

In this case, I know exactly what the underlying error is. (I forgot to set permissions on a stored procedure.) But I really want to (re)enable the error handling so I can find these bugs quickly. Of course, I will remove this once we actually go live for security reasons.

**What other settings are there that could be overriding the default ASP.NET error handling?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [CustomErrors mode="Off"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101693/customerrors-mode-off)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

The **"Off"** must be capitalized correctly.

From "[Editing ASP.NET Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ackhksh7.aspx)":

> Case-Sensitivity
>
> Because tags must be well-formed XML, the tags,
>   subtags, and attributes are case-sensitive. Tag names and attribute
>   names are camel-cased, which means that the first character of a tag
>   name is lowercase and the first letter of any subsequent concatenated
>   word or words is uppercase. In most cases, string attribute values are
>   Pascal-case, which means that the first character is uppercase and the
>   first letter of any subsequent concatenated word or words is
>   uppercase. Exceptions are true and false, which are always lowercase.

Remember kids, you learn something new every day. Even if what you learn is lame.

Comment: +1 for "Remember kids, you learn something new every day. Even if what you learn is lame." :)

Answer (score 7):

You may have `HandleErrorAttribute` global filter in your `Global.asax.cs` file. Remove that line.

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A better, long term solution may be to add [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) to your project, it adds detailed logging to your web project.

Including:

- Logging of nearly all unhandled exceptions.
- A web page to remotely view the entire log of recoded exceptions.
- A web page to remotely view the full details of any one logged exception, including colored stack traces.
- In many cases, you can review the original yellow screen of death that ASP.NET generated for a given exception, even with customErrors mode turned off.
- An e-mail notification of each error at the time it occurs.
- An RSS feed of the last 15 errors from the log.

Answer (score 0):

check if your server uses the same configuration file for your website (if the config file deployed to website dir is the same)