# How to set web.config file to show full error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

I deployed my MVC-3 application on windows Azure. But now when I am requesting it through `staging url` it shows me **(Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.)**. Now I want to see the full error message, by default it is hiding that because of some security reasons. I know that we can do this through web.config file. But how?

Answer (score 303, accepted):

Not sure if it'll work in your scenario, but try adding the following to your `web.config` under `<system.web>`:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

works in my instance.

also see:

[CustomErrors mode="Off"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101693/customerrors-mode-off)

Comment: In addition add the following in the < **System.webServer** > add
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />

Answer (score 170):

This can also help you by showing full details of the error on a client's browser.

```xml
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: For more detail see [customErrors Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: See [httperrors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/)

Comment: See [the difference between customErrors and httpErrors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2481102/7794769)

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer bcuz most devs want to see the details instead of YSOD with no details.

Answer (score 17):

If you're using ASP.NET MVC you might also need to remove the **HandleErrorAttribute** from the Global.asax.cs file:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

Comment: Would I have access to this **Global.asax.cs** file in a `plesk` environment? And where is that file located? The other suggestions are not working; and I need it for a sub-domain.