# ASP.net login label change

Tags: html, asp.net, authentication

I got a problem edit a login..

I want to remove the labels from my login but comes up with an error : Server Error in '/' Application."

Here is the code :

```
<table id="TableData" cellpadding="5">
            <tr>
               <td><tr>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelFirstName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td></tr>
                <td><tr>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelLastName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td></tr>
                <td>
                    <br /><tr>
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelEMail" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEMail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelSeqQuestion" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListSeqQuestions" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelSeqAnswer" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSeqAnswer" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="LabelOptFields" runat="server"></asp:Label>
           </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I cant get it to work anyhow

The reported error was:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.] UpdateProfile.LocalizePage() +681 UpdateProfile.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +514 System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +24 System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +41 System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +131 System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +65 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2427

When I remove `<asp:Label ID="LabelFirstName" runat="server"></asp:Label>`.

Comment: Have you tried debugging ? At least check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665322/how-to-set-web-config-file-to-show-full-error-message and update question with error you're getting

Comment: Thanks @OndrejSvejdar it helps

Comment: Can you please mention the error that you are getting?

Comment: @Shahid " [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   UpdateProfile.LocalizePage() +681
   UpdateProfile.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +514
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +24
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +41
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +131
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +65
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2427 "

Comment: that's when i remove  " <asp:Label ID="LabelFirstName" runat="server"></asp:Label> ". Is there any other way to remove such a label?