# Web Config Remote only in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

When I am debugging my mvc web app an error window is opening instead of my login page, and the error is like

```
    To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on the local server machine, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "RemoteOnly". To enable the details to be viewable on remote machines, please set "mode" to "Off".

    <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

> Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
    <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

can anybody help me out here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set web.config file to show full error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665322/how-to-set-web-config-file-to-show-full-error-message)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have an underlying issue here that needs to be solved before you can get to your login page, but first you'll need to either browse to your app while logged onto the web-server, or update your web.config file so that it looks like the below:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Once this is done, you should at least get the actual error message. Also see

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684665.aspx
- [How to set web.config file to show full error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665322/how-to-set-web-config-file-to-show-full-error-message)