# 500 Internal Server Error accessing Image in IIS7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have created an ASP.Net MVC4 site and deployed it to IIS7.

We noticed that the images in the css were not showing.

Trying to directly access the image file like this
http://.com/CircuitSearch/Images/CircuitSearchBackgroundTrans.png
returns the 500 error. Yes the filepath is correct.

Odd part if another site hosted on the same IIS works fine and can display images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set web.config file to show full error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665322/how-to-set-web-config-file-to-show-full-error-message)

Comment: @AlexK.: That's not a duplicate. It may help the OP solve the issue, but the two questions are totally different.

Comment: Is the Images directory virtual in IIS? Is it pointing to the right folder? Other sites may not have a vdir set up for that. Although thinking about it, that would probably 404 rather than 500.

Comment: my web.config did not have those so I added them. Accessing the site during debug does not proved any errors, just does not show the image. Accessing the image directly does show the 500 error

Comment: Detailed Error Information:
Module    ManagedPipelineHandler
Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
Error Code    0x800703e9
Requested URL    http://localhost:54898/Images/CircuitSearchBackgroundTrans.png
Physical Path    D:\Migration\InterfaceCode\Web\CircutiSearch\OnlineCircuitSearch\OnlineCircuitSearch\Images\CircuitSearchBackgroundTrans.png
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User    Anonymous

Comment: I just recreated the site and added the cshtml and css files to it. Now the image works on index.cshtml but not on the other page.

Comment: I'm having the same problem...sigh.

Answer (score 6):

Change authentication for the site to Anonymous authentication/ application pool identity

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I went into the IIS Log (usually under c:\inetpub\Logs) and discovered that I was getting error 500 with sub status of 19.

I looked up the causes for 500.19 via google and found the below link:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942055/http-error-500-19-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7-0-webpage

Based off a clue that there could be a duplicate entry for some of the modules, handlers, or mime types causing an error, I commented out my system.webServer and noticed the images worked.  I then commented out only portions of my web config and narrowed it down to a duplicate staticContent entry in my web.config.

Comment: Check the web.config.  Mine had a duplicate EntityFramework being inherited from an upper-level directory.