# What do I need to do to publish a website made in c# asp.net on Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I've developed a website in ASP.NET C # in Visual Studio 2013 (no database), for a company. This company wants to replace its current website with the one I've developed. This site is located on the server of a telephone company. How can I replace the old site files with mine, ie, what do I have to do to get my site up and running?

I tried to follow this solution: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/326356/how-to-deploy-an-asp-net-web-application-using-the-copy-project-featur but in step 1 from "Steps to Perform a Copy Project in Visual Studio .NET", the "Copy Project" command is not available.

Comment: That article is about a 15-year-old version of VS.  You should click Publish.

Comment: USe this => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/

Comment: It was updated 2 months ago..

Comment: Visual Studio .NET is the original version of VS, from 2002.

Comment: the link is mentioning asp.net Web Application, and in the tags you have asp.net mvc. Different things so either tags are not correct or the link is about different type of project than you actually have

Comment: Is that the only commentary you have to make @PawełŁukasik? lol

Comment: @miguelcarreira I don't see your code so can't tell which is true of those two. Now you've updated the tags so it's clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio solution, Right click and select publish
in the publishing dialog, select publish to local directory and obtain the deployment files. then place it in your IIS (in a new website) and make sure everything is working. once you are comfortable,

1. backup your existing website's files ( zip would be a easy and fast option)
2. remove existing files
3. place your files( published files) with old files.

that's it and for troubleshooting(if any)

1. set custom error mode to OFF [How to set web.config file to show full error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665322/how-to-set-web-config-file-to-show-full-error-message)"
2. carefully read the error and try to understand what the error message. and configure your website accordingly.

> Just take the leap of faith...

Comment: By local directory you mean "File system" on the Publish method?

Comment: People often chose to publish to local folder on the same machine as an intermediate location, and THEN manually copy to the final destination. I typically publish directly to a network share on the actual web server. Of course this is a quick and simple way. In more mature project you would have the sources packaged and deployed to intermediate location using CI server, and NOT the publish method from VS (and later moved to the final destination by a CD/release method)