# ASP.NET website deploys but only I can see

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, iis

I have a prototype .net web site that is on Windows 10, created using C#. I am using IIS on the same machine to deploy from Visual Studio 2017. It uses SQL Server for back-end data. The site only runs on intranet.

It deploys ok, I can see all the pages, from all three of my machines. But others cannot see anything. They get a run-time error, that does not say anything specific.

My machine was re-imaged and hence the need to redo this.

I looked at IIS log and it does not have any info. What else I can look into?

Comment: How about posting the run time error, to see if someone here can figure it out. It could be a windows firewall issue, maybe a DNS issue. Can't tell with some kind of error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `web.config`, turn off custom error mode to see detailed error message on the client:

[How to set web.config file to show full error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665322/how-to-set-web-config-file-to-show-full-error-message)

If it works locally and not remotely, it's likely a permissions error (accessing a resource that the client doesn't have access to), or maybe a pathing issue (you are referring somewhere to something by disk or UNC instead of URL, or to a domain that only makes sense to you, like `localhost`).

Comment: I did, thanks. Now I see the following error in SQL log.
Login failed for user 'domain\user name'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
The user is supposed to log in as network service account from the web browser in a .net app.

Comment: Login failed for user 'domain\user name'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>] Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5

The above is the er\ror.