# Published site to Windows 2012 Getting An error occurred while processing your request

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created an ASP.NET MVC (ASP>NET Wen Application.net Framework)site using Visual Studio 2019. All worked fine on my Windows 10 using IIS Express.

I then published it to a Windows 2012 Server-IIS. It seems the _Layout page is OK but every page (all have a sql connection - sql on a different server) I get the message Error.

This issue seems to be fixed in debugging by changing the Document Type to 10?

Am I missing some settings in IIS? What other information would be useful in troubleshooting this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11665322/11683

Comment: Check the connection string

Comment: Sorry not sure how that error message got in my post. Everything displays just layouts are messed up and tables are not right. If I hit F12 in IE and change the document mode to 10, this seems to fix the issue.