# How do I troubleshoot this error my when loading my View using MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Is there a log or something I can look at.
All I am doing is loading my page:

```
https://applications.staging.somesite.edu/Apps/LeadAssessmentApp/Home/Index
```

and I am receiving this error message: "an Error has occurred while processing your request".
Is there a way to trouble shoot what is happening or prevent it in the code?

Here is the Index in the HomeController

```
public ContentResult Index()
        {
 
            --- authenticate and retrieve the data to send back ---

            return Content("");
        }
```

I am concerned this could happen again, it seems to be corrected when we refreshed the app pool, but I am not certain why it was working and then just stopped and I would like to try to capture the errors. I did retrieve the IIS logs so maybe there is something in there.

Comment: Please update the question with more context? It's unclear what this is about.

Comment: Does the error happen when debugging locally?

Comment: It does not happen locally

Comment: You may be able to update your web.config to show full error messages. Please see the answer AND COMMENT here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665322/how-to-set-web-config-file-to-show-full-error-message