# Not able to set up <customErrors mode="off"> for a mvc3 .net web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, web-config

I need set CustomErrors on OFF in my web.config in IIS 7.5 for my MVC 3 web app.

Using this code the CustomError are still in default mode.

Could you tell me what I'm ding wrong here? Thansk

```
 <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="off">
</customErrors>
...
```

EDIT Solution (case sensitive problem)

```
 <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off">
</customErrors>
...
```

Comment: Make sure you are modifying the root level web.config

Comment: Thanks, yes I am modifying the root level web.config

Comment: Maybe some problem with machine.config?

Comment: I believe it's case sensitive... try "Off" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101693/customerrors-mode-off

Comment: you were right it was case sensitive. If you like write a former answer I would be glad to accept it :-) thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

customErrors is case sensitive.

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off">
    </customErrors>
...
</system.web>
```