# Global.asax Application_Error issues

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to handle uncaught exceptions in my Global.asax's Application_Error event.  It currently looks like

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender as object, ByVal e as EventArgs)
    Server.ClearError()
    Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPages/GenericError.aspx")
End Sub
```

Throwing a brand new exception in the Page_load of another page with

```
Throw New Exception()
```

What ends up actually happening is that execution never leaves the source page, and throws the default asp error page citing my exception.  Why isn't it being sent to my error page?

EDIT: fixed `Response.Redirect`.  Now looks like:

```
Response.Redirect("http://mysite/ErrorPages/GenericError.aspx")
```

Also made the change to my `web.config` file that was suggested by [krshekhar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14777447/312777) suggested.  While I am now being sent to my error page, it is using the default redirection instead of the one I feed it in `Application_Error`.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Have you got CustomerErrors turned on or off in the web.config?

Comment: FYI using `Response.Redirect` like that throws a `ThreadAbortException`. [MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The solution should be `customErrors mode="On"`

The only problem looks for your qustion is web.config entry for customError it should be as follows

```
 <configuration>
    <system.web>
       <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
           <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
           <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
            ...
       </customErrors>
    </system.web>
  </configuration>
```

Helpful links

[ASP.NET custom error page - Server.GetLastError() is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343014/asp-net-custom-error-page-server-getlasterror-is-null)

[CustomErrors mode="Off"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101693/customerrors-mode-off)

Comment: Changed the `web.config` as suggested.  I get to the error page now, but it is using the default redirection from `<customErrors>` and not the redirection I feed it in `Application_Error`.

Comment: @Crimius remove the `defaultRedirect` and use `Response.Redirect("pagename",false)`

Comment: The page now errors due to there being no default redirect in the `<customErrors>` tag.