# Show real error instead of GenericErrorPage in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

My program is already attached in the IIS. When there is an error, it only shows the genericErrorPage. I want to see the real error. Is there any way?

Comment: i cant understand your question sorry can u explain more!!

Comment: I load my program using the IP Address of my server. When it has errors, it only shows the GenericErrorPage.htm instead of the REAL error (like when you only use localhost). I'm sorry if it's not really clear.

Comment: Please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101693/customerrors-mode-off