# An application error occurrs on the server with published website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a website for my final year project using Visual Studio 2013, ASP.NET and C#.
It is an online CV creator so the user enters their details and presses submit and a PDF is generated (iTextSharp).

The problem is that it runs fine from Visual Studio but when I publish it online, it gives me an error which can be found below.

> **Runtime Error**
>    *Description:* An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 
>   Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
 <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.
 <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
enter code here
```

The link to my site is http://myonlinecvcreator.azurewebsites.net/CV

Comment: Without the actual error, we can't help you.  Do as that error message suggests and run the browser on the local server machine or set the `mode` attribute of `customErrors` to `Off` in the web.config

Comment: possible duplicate of [CustomErrors mode="Off"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101693/customerrors-mode-off)

Comment: Is it possible that you deployed debug version of the code and thus you have a wrong connection string in the web.config? just a wild guess.

Answer (score 1):

On the server, inside the folder of your application, you will find a file named web.config.

Inside this file, you will have to add those lines into it :

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

In fact, the tag configuration is already inside it. So you will have to insert the 3 other lines inside the "configuration".

Then, run your cv creator again and see what the real error is.

ps : new error = new question. But search a little bit before posting again, otherwise people will get angry.

Comment: Im now getting a new error. Should i set up a new question?

Comment: Editing your previous question is enough in this case.