# mono ubuntu Runtime Error A runtime error has occurred

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop, ubuntu-14.04

my web.config  is as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
Web.config file for first.

The settings that can be used in this file are documented at 
http://www.mono-project.com/Config_system.web and 
http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5ysx397.aspx
-->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation defaultLanguage="C#" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Net, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <authentication mode="None">
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <httpHandlers>
    </httpHandlers>
    <trace enabled="true" localOnly="true" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="10" traceMode="SortByTime" />
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
    <pages>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

```
when I run it 

it gives me an error like \   



Application Exception
Runtime Error
A runtime error has occurred
```

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed (for security reasons).

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
 <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

    <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
    <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->    
    <configuration>    
        <system.web>    
            <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>    
        </system.web>    
    </configuration>
```

Comment: A quick search using Google reveals:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101693/customerrors-mode-off

Answer (score 0):

A quick search using Google reveals:

[CustomErrors mode="Off"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101693/customerrors-mode-off)

Basically you need to adjust a few other settings