# How can I enable detailed errors in IIS Express from within Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis-express

Using VS 2015 and Firefox browser. When my code runs into an error I see it in the Output window, but would prefer seeing it in the browser. Right now all I get is a 500 error with no stack.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into the `<customErrors />` of your `web.config` (example below):

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
                    mode="RemoteOnly">
         <error statusCode="500"
                redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
      </customErrors>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

See also this previous SO answer: [CustomErrors mode="Off"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101693/customerrors-mode-off)

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.71).aspx