# Getting Run time Error while publishing solution to Azure web-App

Tags: azure, umbraco7

I created one Empty application in visual studio and install umbraco cms using nuget package manager.

after that i have made some doc type,template and other things. all things are working fine in localhost.

But when i publish this to azure getting run time error.

[image]
i changed the

> customErrors mode="Off"

.

but its not working,

any help would be appreciated,

Thanks,

Ronak Panchal.

Comment: Please describe this better - what code is failing? Are you connecting to a different database in Azure? Is that set up right? Your question is near impossible to answer without more specific information.

Comment: Please show us your web.config content

Comment: yes i'm connecting to a different database in Azure.and i updated connection string in web config its working fine in local host.
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
</system.web>

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the article [CustomErrors mode="Off"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101693/customerrors-mode-off). You need to set `<deployment retail="false" />` in your web.config and change `<customErrors mode="off"/>` to `<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/>`.

Comment: I can't find machine config file in my solution.
i found in whole solution 'deployment retail' but no match found with this word.

Comment: can you change that <CustomErrors mode="Off" /> between system.web to <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/>  in you web.config and try again?

Comment: i tried but it gives me below error .
The element 'httpErrors' has invalid child element 'customErrors'. List of possible elements expected: 'error, remove, clear'.

Comment: what's your ASP.NET version? If 1.1, pls update to 2.0 then try again.