# ASP.NET rewriting web.config when website starts

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have a web site (as distinct from application) where the customerrors properties are defined in the Web.Config file like so:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" />
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.1">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

When the web site is first called upon, the web.config CHANGES, and the customerrors properties now look like this:

```
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
            <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
          </assemblies>
        </compilation>
    </system.web>
```

Can anyone explain to me what is happening and why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CustomErrors mode="Off"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101693/customerrors-mode-off)

Comment: When you compile your website, did you do it as release or debug? Make sure it's in Release build.

Comment: Perhaps I should be clear - I meant that is specifically a web site, as opposed to a Web Application. It gets compiled on demand...

And thanks for taking the time...