# <customErrors mode="Off"/> not working when uploaded code on server

Tags: c#, web-config

I added the following to all the web.configs in my app. But I still can't see the errors remotely. How could this be?

```
 <configuration>
 <system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101693/customerrors-mode-off) link. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

the reason is, you need to set `debug` to true:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" />
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

`customErrors mode` is meant for debugging purposes and won't work once deployed to the server unless you set `compilation debug="true"`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but i have already used <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" /> in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue seeing the yellow screen of death, too. So, instead I sent the output of the exception to a log file by setting stdoutLogEnabled="true" and stdoutLogFile="C:\Users\SomeUser\LoggingDirectory\LogFileName". In this case, you'll get a log file named something like LogFileName_20220607193533_9648.txt.

BE SURE TO RESET IIS.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Project.Name.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="C:\Users\SomeUser\LoggingDirectory\LogFileName" hostingModel="OutOfProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Disclaimer: I'm not certain that you need the "customErrors mode='Off'" part but, it was there when this solution worked for me.