# Old VB.Net websites throws CutomError page after switching to another Application Pool

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-8, application-pool, custom-errors

Foremost, I am in a strict unique environment where VS cannot be installed on the network (On server, or workstation), so I cannot debug locally or remotely via VS.
I am trying to move this website written in VB.NET to another server.
The application pool setting for the new server is the same as the old server.
Copied the system files from the old server to the new one, and its giving me the CustomError page.
I tried to switch to another application pool in the new server, and it works but without access to the db (different service account/permissions), so pretty sure its not the code
and since the old server website still works using the same service account, I am certain its not the permission.

I also have tried setting the CustomError in web.config to custom error page, still giving the same CustomError page

I have tried setting the CustomError to Off in web.config, gave me the same CustomError page.
With CustomError=Off
 - tried [existingResponse="PassThrough" errorMode="Detailed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640526/detailed-500-error-message-asp-iis-7-5/2640607#2640607)
 - tried [setting through ASP.Net Tab, Edit configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101693/customerrors-mode-off)
all resulted with the same CustomError.

Any suggestions would be great, thanks

Comment: Could you please share the details web.config file? As far as I know, we have two kings of the custom error page setting for the IIS. One is for system.web tag another is for the system.webserver.   Besides, I suggest you could check your web application code to make sure you don't set the any logic to redirect the page if it through the error.  We could set the it by using global.asax file's application_error function.

Comment: @BrandoZhang
here's the web.config
`<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
`
Besides the appsetting and connectionstring, I took everything out, and still showing that customererror page

Comment: Have you tired to clear the browser's cache or use another browser and try again?

Comment: @BrandoZhang Yes I have, tried refresh the client side, and the server side (i.e. restart app pool, restart server).  All the same result.  I event added a new app pool with fresh default setting, samething.