# When I first start up website by clicking the link, it shows the error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxepD.jpg)

I am fresher in ASP.Net C# (4.0). I developed one website and upload to a server. It works in my local system. But when i upload to the server, page displays one error in web.config. AND ERROR IS...

> Runtime Error Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

Comment: I think these answers will be enought to solve the problem 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101693/customerrors-mode-off

Answer (score 0):

Your detail is clear enough,To see what caused this error add codes below to your webconfig inside `configuration` section and then try again

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: or, as the error suggests, access the website from the server through localhost