# How do I prevent Server Error page from showing in IIS for a .net application. I have debug=false

Tags: .net, iis, config

I have debug=false but I am still getting the "Server Error" page.
In my web.config I have:

```html
<compilation debug="false" defaultLanguage="c#" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

When I look in UI in IIS at every level I see:
[image]
But I still get the following error message instead of a generic 500 page:
[image]
I have messed with a bunch of the settings and can't seem to get anything to work. What setting will prevent the stack trace from showing?

Comment: you probably miss the settings <customErrors mode="Off/On"> in your Web.Config

Comment: Could you please check if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101693/customerrors-mode-off) can help your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cleared up everything for me: https://www.basrijnbout.nl/blog/6/
I went with the Bypassing CustomErrors solution that was mentioned.